# How do I disable errors on string truncation in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2000

How can I tell SQL Server not to raise an error if I insert or update a string longer than the size of the field - I would like silent truncation in this instance.

Answer (score 40):

The thing you have to do is set ANSI WARNINGS to OFF
You can do that by calling

```
set ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF
```

I have also written a practical example:

```
create table bla(id varchar(2))
go

insert bla values ('123') --fails


set ANSI_WARNINGS  OFF

insert bla values ('123') --succeeds
```

Do remember to turn the ANSI warnings back ON when you are done.
You can do so by calling:

```
set ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Answer (score 2):

Try casting the variable to the exact type and length before inserting it.  That might do the trick.  Casting (and converting) are much more flexible. :)